# Getting place where two dives overlap each other

Tags: javascript, css

I got two circles that are animated to overlap each other. Is there a way to get back the common part and change its color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beljems/jagr3zdr/) I have created for you. Is this what you want? I used `jquery` in animating those circles.